# Disable back, reload/refresh, change location/url

Tags: angularjs

How can i disable changing $location or reloading $location if my form is still invalid, or while uploading file

```
windowElement.on('beforeunload', function(event) {
  if(form === false) {
  event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

i also tried

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event) {
  if(form === false) {
  event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

and

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(event) {
  if(form === false) {
  event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

all of them are not working